# SQL Server stops responding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I work on a database where we store sales of about 300 stores. There is 1 table per store and the total amount of lines is about 120 million (4 million for the biggest table).

The machine is a windows server 2008 R2 on a citrix virtual machine with 65Gb memory and SQL Server version is 2014.

Lines are added from the stores to the database via a webservice every minute so that customers (the store ownsers) can view their stats almost almost in real time.

Christmas is close and the amount of sales per day is increasing, it is now something like 100k lines per day.

The monitor says there is about 100-200 queries per second, they are all before their statistics and therefore query a lot of data.

Database I/O says about 0.1Mb/s ~ 0.5Mb/s.

CPU goes from 10% to 50%.

Often, the database server stop responding (no more connection possible) for about 30 sec ~ 2 min and I don't know why.

Is there any way I can find out why ?
Should I upsize or do something else ?
As data is not relational at all, may I go to a nosql solution for better availability ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because I think it is a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you using a clustered index?  Do you have an identity primary key, or are you using something else like a GUID?

Comment: If you want to learn more about tuning your database, check out http://www.amazon.ca/T-SQL-Querying-Itzik-Ben-Gan/dp/0735685045/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1450373337&sr=8-3&keywords=Itzik+ben+gan

Comment: This could be out of date statistics.  Indexes may be fragmented, but that is usually less of a concern.  What does Activity Monitor show when it stops responding?  I would not recommend a NoSql solution unless maybe you are Facebook, Google, Amazon, etc.

Comment: Yes there is a clustered primary key bigint identity.
The indexes are reorganized every night if they are fragmented at more than 40% with 1000 fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a hardware problem. 
Everything is back to normal after changing the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

We use SQL Server and it can handle that much data. The [profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) should give you some useful information.

If the data is not relational nosql will be faster. Depending on your needs the most recent version of [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) is worth checking out.